# Git merge single file from another repository into my own

Tags: git, version-control

Say I have my own git repo with a bunch of text files in it. There is another different git repo that someone else owns with a bunch of text files that all differ from my own except for one file.

I am continuously making changes to the different text files in my repo, but every now and then I want to merge any changes of that single file from the other repo into my own.

Is there any easy way of going about doing this? I've searched around and found some similar questions but none that we're for my exact scenario.

Comment: If you're not changing that file yourself, then just copy it and commit.

Comment: I am changing the file I want to merge with.

Comment: Well, depending on how frequently it is changed at both sides it might still be simplest to just copy it and resolve any conflicts that arise. If it were a directory/library I would suggest having it as a submodule, but for one file... anyway, the right thing to do, when you can help it, is for everyone who collaborates on a file to work on forks of the same repository. There's no way to just grab the detached history of one file in Git in order to merge it to a completely different repository AFAIK.

Comment: Kdiff3 or other similar merging applications help me out a lot with merging different repositories with nearly the same code.

Answer (score 12):

Try to add the `other-repo` then bring its branches including your `target-branch`

```
git remote add other git@github.com:username/other-repo.git
git fetch other
```

Switch to the branch you want to merge in the `target-file.ext`:

```
git checkout your-branch
```

Merge the target file into yours:

```
git checkout -p other/target-branch target-file.ext
```

Answer (score 6):

You can merge arbitrary files or repo objects.  Simplest might be:

```
git merge-file file.txt <(git show last-merged-file.txt) /path/to/their/file.txt
# resolve any conflicts, then
git tag last-merged-file.txt `git hash-object-w file.txt`
```

Comment: Good answer, but I would like an explanation of what's going on.

Comment: @timgeb Does matching the docs against the commands leave you with any specific questions?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your current directory, This way I'm doing currently, I hope you will help too.

```
cd your_current_git_Directory
```

Set your username and repository of another repository/second(from want to copy)

```
git remote add -f repo-b git@github.com:<username>/<repository>.git
```

Now, Merge the filename you looking for(if you want file merge subfolder)

```
git checkout -p repo-b/master  <folder_name>/<filename>
```

Or merge filename only

```
git checkout -p repo-b/master  <filename>
```

And Remove repository

```
git remote rm repo-b
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any kind of packaging (artifacts) results in the original repo, then you can ask the owner of the repo to publish the sources as well. Then in your own repo you consume and unpack such artifact and just copy the file you need. E.g. If using Java-Maven, make sure the build on the original repo publishes also the sources, then in your own repo, you put a pre-step (before compile) in which you download the sources dependency, unpack the jar file and copy the one you need to your proper directory. There are maven plugins for that